# Why do I lose draggable after drag?

Tags: jquery-ui, backbone.js, draggable

I just migrated to backbone and have a strange behaviour.
I attach draggable to an element which is created by a script, thus not directly available in DOM.
EDIT:
The element that is created is `.nav`, `$("#viewer")` as container is already in the DOM.

In plain jQuery i used `.on` and `mousemove` event for this and it worked.

With backbone I use the same in the initialize method:

```
initialize: function(options) {
            this.viewer = $("#viewer");
            this.viewer.on("mousemove", '.nav', function() {
                $(this).draggable();
            });
```

This seems to work, but only one time.
After dragging the element one time, I can't drag it anymore.

Are there conflicts with the events? Am I missing something?

Comment: Is #viewer already part of the DOM, is it is part of this particular view? If it's part of your view it's probably not available until the 'render' function, after you've placed it in the DOM...i.e. this.$el.html(compiledTemplate)

Comment: yes, #viewer is already there and part of this view. It does work for one time, then the .nav element is not draggable anymore. I suspect that the mouse events are "stolen" somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to refer to `$('#viewer')` after you've called `render()`. `initialize` is called before `render`, and so the DOM element doesn't exist.

Also, use `this.$('#viewer')`, and it will grab the element (after `render`) even if it hasn't been appended to your page's DOM.

```
myView = new ExampleView({ model: myModel });
$(body).append(myView.render().el);

myView.onRender();

// -------------

// Now on your view:

onRender: function() {

  this.viewer = this.$('#viewer');
  this.viewer.on("mousemove", '.nav', function() {
    $(this).draggable();
  });

},
```

#### UPDATE

You can also, to make such things simpler, customize Backbone to automatically call the `onRender()` function after rendering, by triggering an event or something.

Marionette.js (a Backbone.js extension) has this built in and I use it all the time.

Comment: i dont use render() here, i just call ```var viewer = new Viewer(settings);``` and $('#viewer') is already in the DOM. I tried your approach but didnt succeed. As i said it works one time, so i guess its sucessfully applied, but then looses the draggable behaviour. Do i have to explicitly bind something here?

Comment: Okay got it. Well, my next question is: Why do you bind draggable on every mousemove of the nav? You are going to end up assigning that event listener to the `#viewer` 500 times(!), and who knows what jQuery is going to do in that case.

Comment: Simply try `this.$('#viewer').draggable();` on initialize then and see what happens. You can also add some debugging, like try hooking on to the `onDrag` or `dragStart` param in jQuery draggable and do some logging to see if it even arrives there.

Comment: yes the mousemove bind was some kind of a hack, to get the draggable applied when the .nav element gets created. is there a better way to bind it?

Comment: +1 for your efforts, the solution however were the outdated version, see my answer

Answer (score 1):

The solution finally was pretty easy:

make sure you dont use outdated versions of backbone.js and underscore!!

After i updated the versions to latest I made it work with:

```
render: function() {
  this.viewer.on("mouseover", '.nav', function() {
                if (!$(this).data("init")) {
                    $(this).data("init", true);
                    $(this).draggable();
                }
            });
```

Probably still not very elegant but i couldnt made the suggested onRender method from dc2 work.